# How to get the data from database and echo on PHP page

Tags: php

How to get the data from database and echo on PHP page?

---

Mycode :

```php
$emailto = $_POST["email"];
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id from  enseignant where email = $emailto)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$emailto);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

---

but I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Comment: Please share more details. What does `$con->prepare` return? Also, there's no parameter in the prepared query

Comment: $con connect to my database  and the syntax :$mysqli -> prepare(query)

Comment: You should study PHP/MySql a little bit more before posting questions here. There's a bunch of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use questionmark in place of the parameter you want to set with bind_param(). The following code should work

```
$emailto=$_POST["email"];
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id from enseignant where email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$emailto);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: the same don't work